# I have accepted answers for all my questions but my accept rate shows 86%

Tags: support, accept-rate

I recently (Dec. 31, 2009) as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986078/how-do-i-call-dotnetfactory-from-vbscript-in-a-stand-alone-vbs-file) on Stack Overflow. Before voting up and accepting an answer, I had a 100% accept rate. After voting up the answer I was going to accept and then accepting it (today, January 3, 2010), my accept rate now shows 86%.

Now, I understand that accept rate is a batch job, and there is a possibility that its results and my accepting of the question may have occurred at the same time. Is it correct to assume that my accept rate dropped because I did not accept an answer within 48 hours of the question? Assuming I don't ask any further questions with unaccepted answers, when should I expect it to climb back up to 100% again?

Comment: I must have just hit the timing wrong, as my accept rate is back at 100%. I would still like to know when the effect of a question with no accepted answers affects accept rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accept rate is heavily cached. Wait a couple days, it'll get updated.

Comment: @Fearless - So what you're saying is it doesn't matter when I accept answers, as long as I do the job will eventually catch up to the stored data and correct the stats? Even if the question/answer are really old?

Answer (score 6):

patience, grasshopper.
you jump faster than the world--
trust it will catch up.

Comment: +1 simply for the haiku and the use of "grasshopper"