# my accept rate is 75%, with only one Q not accepted

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

My Accept rate status sits at 75% yet only 1 of my 12 questions has no accepted answer. What's up with that? It shouldn't be a [cache issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/i-have-accepted-answers-for-all-my-questions-but-my-accept-rate-shows-86-closed) as I've not accepted anything for 25 days.

I'm not concerned, just noticing a loose thread and wondering why it is that way. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community wiki questions are not included when computing the accept rate.

Comment: For more detail, you can refer to this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-the-acceptance-rate-and-how-does-it-work/16729#16729